# Graphviz as a standalone OS independent standard executable

Tags: graphviz, dot

I'm working on a Rust project which uses the Graphviz library. Currently, I'm working on Ubuntu-based system where first I need to install Graphviz then I can use commands like:

> dot -Tsvg test.gv -O

But what I need is a standalone executable that I can bundle up with my Rust project, so:

1. Whoever is using the project doesn't have to install Graphviz as a dependency first in their system.
2. I can use the bundled Graphviz executable to run the commands which are not dependent on the fact that the user has Graphviz installed or not.
3. It should be OS-independent so I can run the Graphviz dot command from the project on every platform.

So, is there any way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I'm using Electron to integrate with Graphviz and use on any OS. I'm using [a node module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@hpcc-js/wasm) that works beautifully with Graphviz and also supports the HTML-like label (expat library) too.